# Find limit sup and limit inf for the sequence $ x_n = \sin(\frac{n\pi}{2}) \cos(\frac{n\pi}{3})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, supremum-and-infimum

I need to find the $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ of the following sequence
$$
x_n = \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right) \cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right).
$$
I was trying to take subsequences as $n_k=12k, 12k+1, 12k+2,.......,12k+11$ but this will take long time to evaluate them. Is there a faster way to find the values of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$?

Comment: **Hint:** Your sequence is $12-$ periodic, and you can compute each term excatly.

Comment: I was about to say that. In this case, computing the multiple different possible values and then taking the maximum and minimum will give the lim sup and lim inf respective;y.

Comment: So, as I said evaluate the six values related to 12k....., knowing that when the subsequence is even the value is zero so I comupute the odd terms

Comment: Try to express $x_n$ as $\frac 12\left(\sin\left(\frac{5\pi n}{6}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{\pi n}{6}\right)\right)$

Answer (score 1):

We can say that:
$$\sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}\right)=\left\{0,1,0,-1,0,1,0\right\} \,\,\, n=0,\dots,6$$
And:
$$\cos\left(\frac{n\pi}{3}\right)=\left\{1,\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2},-1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},1\right\}\,\,\, n=0,\dots,6$$

So:
$$\sup(x_n)=\max(x_n)=1$$
And:
$$\inf(x_n)=\min(x_n)=0$$

Comment: @Student:  if this answer has been useful, let me know smashing that +1 or accepted answer buttons.